# Notification of row entries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, trigger, alerts

I have SQL Server 2012 machine housing a database running an off the shelf application with a users table. This users table contains PII enterable fields. Per requirement none of our databases can house PII. I have a job set up to scrub any rows not null that runs daily. I am wondering if there is a way to set up a job or trigger that can alert administrators anytime data is entered into one of these PII rows and perhaps have the scrub job run automatically anytime one of the PII fields is updated with anything other than NULL?

Comment: So there are multiple columns in the users table 30 +. There are about 10 columns that I would want to be set to null anytime a new row is added to the users table (new user created) or anytime something in the user table is updated (user updating profile). The colums are email, birthday, street_1, street_2, b_phone1.... Hopefully this makes it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to create an after insert/update trigger which would join the base `users` table with the virtual `inserted` table and force the PII columns to be null (or other scrubbing logic).  Here is a very simple example:

```
--create test table
drop table if exists [dbo].[UserTable]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserTable] (
    [id] [int] NULL
    ,[BirthDate] DATE NULL
    ,[Street1] VARCHAR(30) NULL
    ,[Street2] VARCHAR(30) NULL
    ,[SSN] VARCHAR(9) NULL
    ,[OtherColumn1] VARCHAR(100)
    ,[OtherColumn2] VARCHAR(100)
    ,[OtherColumn3] VARCHAR(100)
    ,
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


--create after insert/update trigger to force PII fields to null
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UserTable_InsertedOrUpdated] ON [dbo].[UserTable]
AFTER INSERT
    ,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE ut
    SET ut.birthdate = NULL
        ,ut.Street1 = NULL
        ,ut.Street2 = NULL
        ,ut.SSN = null
    FROM UserTable ut
    JOIN inserted i ON i.id = ut.id
END
GO


--test an insert 
INSERT INTO UserTable (id,Birthdate,Street1,street2,SSN,OtherColumn1,OtherColumn2,OtherColumn3)
VALUES (1,'1960-01-01','Street1','Street2','111111111','OtherColumn1','OtherColumn2','OtherColumn3')
INSERT INTO UserTable (id,Birthdate,Street1,street2,SSN,OtherColumn1,OtherColumn2,OtherColumn3)
VALUES (2,'1960-01-01','Street1','Street2','111111111','OtherColumn1','OtherColumn2','OtherColumn3')

--test an update
UPDATE UserTable
SET SSN = '999' where id = 1

--check the contents of the table
SELECT *
FROM UserTable
```

Comment: I would add a "WHERE foo.SSN IS NOT NULL" to avoid the double tap on the table if it's not needed.

Comment: @JonathanFite - agreed - there may be many additional columns that hold PII and the OP would need to include additional logic in the trigger to check those.

Comment: This might be a good case for using [COLUMNS_UPDATED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columns-updated-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [UPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as well, since we only care if certain columns change.

Comment: So is there a way to set up a trigger to set values to null anytime data is entered into specific PII columns such as: birthday, street_1, street_2, ssn etc on a single table that contains 30+ columns? If so what would the TSQL look like to create such a trigger?

Comment: @GregGoodson - I updated my answer with an example of updating multiple columns to `null` during insert or update.